# Web Assembly Have client read text file on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want my client app to read a text file stored on the server. I can't get past the step to of passing a parameter from the client to the controller. I keep getting 404 errors. I'm new and lost. Can someone help me?

**Controller:**

```
namespace Training.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/controller")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ReadTextController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("{filename}")]
        public string[] Getfile(string filename)
        {

            string[] ret = new string[3];
            ret[0] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            ret[1] = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
            ret[2] = "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";
            return ret;
        }

    }
}
```

**Client Method**

```
private async Task Euler13()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    string param = "Euler13.txt";
    string[]? jj = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<string[]>($"api/ReadText/{param}");

    sw.Stop();
    TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
    elapsedTime[2] = String.Format($"{ts.Seconds:00}:{ts.Milliseconds:0000} sec");
}
```

Comment: Use `[Route("api/[controller]")]` instead. Right now you specify that the controllers listens to `api/controller`. You'd have to use `$"api/controller/{param}"` instead of `$"api/ReadText/{param}"`

Comment: When debugging programs like this, it is often useful to check if the problem is on the server or client. I.e. How does the final query URI look like? Is it as you would expect? Can you use it in a browser?  I.e. try to identify the component that is faulty.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue?

Comment: Fixing the syntax error worked perfectly